# Import autocorrect library from word to google doc

Tags: ms-word, google-drive-api, ms-office, google-docs

I'm planning to switch from Microsoft Word to Google Docs since it has better collaboration options. However, I have set up an extensive auto-correct library in Microsoft Word over the course of 3 years. If I switch to Docs now, I'll have to set them up all over again. A rather daunting task.

I found out that all the auto-correct entries in Word are stored in a file called MSO1033.acl, but I can't find anything that would help me import the auto-correct library from it to Google Docs. Any idea?

Comment: According to the response to your question posted in [google forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/DRqUkUtlCPA) , this is not possible. You will have to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

The question was about Word's AutoCorrect entries, not custom dictionaries. Although the suggestion to use Auto Hotkey or Selenium still applies.

This is obviously a two-step process: 1) export from Word, 2) Import into Google Docs --> Tools --> Preferences.

1) EXPORT:

Earlier versions of MS Office shipped with a support.dot file that contained various macros, including one for backing up and restoring AutoCorrect entries. While it is very old (c. 2000 I think) it still works and is still available from various sources if you search for it.

This will allow you to extract the AutoCorrect entries into a word document, which can then be saved as a .txt file or whatever.

2) IMPORT - The Missing Link!

There does not seem to exist at the moment a script to import new spelling corrections into Docs. So someone needs to write it. As the proud owner of 22,000 Word AutoCorrect entries who is now a Google Docs fan I'd do this myself!

Except that https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/ doesn't seem to provide an API for Tools-->Preferences, which makes what should be a straightforward task quite tricky.

Answer (score 0):

#### Custom Dictionaries in Word

Your custom dictionaries are stored by Word in *.dic files. There files are plaintext files where each entry is in a separate row.

The custom dictionaries are stored at various locations within your user profile:

- %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\15.0\\Proofing\RoamingCustom.dic
- %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Spelling\\default.dic
- %APPDATA%\Microsoft\UProof\CUSTOM.DIC

You can see all custom dictionaries via *File* -> *Options* -> *Proofing* -> *Custom Dictionaries...*

[image: Word Custom Dictionaries]

#### Manually Importing to Google Docs

There is no direct way to import a list of Word (i.e. a Microsoft Word custom dictionary) into Google Docs. Google Docs provides an interface for adding single Word to a (single) custom dictionary. To access the interface open a document and select *Personal Dictionary...* from the *Tools* menu:

[image: Google Docs Personal Dictionary]

If you only have to add a few entries, manually entering the words is probably the fastest way to transfer your dictionaries.

#### Automatically Importing to Google Docs

If you have a lot of words in your custom dictionaries, you can automate your browser, e.g. using a tool such as **AutoHotKey** or **Selenium**.